# Array values sum and passed as click argument

Tags: jquery

I've got an array of values that i'm using to create list items that I then append to an ordered list.

What i want to to is create a click function that passes the sum of those values based on the order of the items in the list (ie if you click on the 3rd item in the list it totals all the preceeding values and passes that sum to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just loop over your array, summing the values.  We only really need to know intIndex to do this, not objValue.

```
var jList = $("#bargraph ul").addClass('bars');

// for each item in your array, create an LI
$.each(datas,function(intIndex, objValue){
    var intSum = 0, i = 0;

    for (i; i < intIndex; i++) {
        // just to make sure you don't try and access an array value out of bounds
        if (i >= datas.length) {
            break;
        }

        intSum += datas[intSum];
    }

    jList.append($("<li>"+"</li>").addClass('bar'+intIndex).css('height', objValue).attr('data-sum', intSum));
});

// for each LI, add an event listener
$("#bargraph li").on('click', function(e) {
    // here's your value
    currentSlide = $(this).attr('data-sum');
});
```

In retrospect, there's better ways to do it.  I'd rather move all the logic to the event listener for calculating the sum.  In which case you could use the jquery selector to get the array of all the LIs, loop over them until you reach the current one, summing their height attributes.  But for now, this should work.

Comment: I want to pass the summed values to a variable "currentSlide" im using as a counter. The idea is for the user to click on a created list item and have the click navigate to the "currentSlide" which would be the summed value of that list item and all the preceeding items in the list. Make sense?

Comment: trying to integrate this into what ive got going. I really appreciate the help duncan.

Comment: Thanks for the help but i keep getting an error on the event listener. It doesn't seem to be picking up the ul inside the #bargraph div.

Comment: Can you add some more code to your original question, showing your HTML structure containing the UL and the #bargraph div?

Comment: I've posted what i've got working up until this point. Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var jList = $("#bargraph ul").attr('class', 'bars');
```

I don't think that is doign what you want, it is attempting to set the attribute "class" to "bars". If you want to add a class you should use [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).  To select using class you can do this :

```
var jList = $(".bars");
```

And selectors can be combined.

Comment: It's doing what's intended. im adding the class "bars" to the unordered list then im appending the list items to that unordered list. I'm not trying to select using class. i'm trying to get the value of objValue, add objValue to all the preceeding values of objValue, and pass that sum to a variable that im using as a counter.

Comment: using attr removes any other classes that the element has, it resets them to whatever you pass in.